MySQL transaction does not work in Powershell script
I have a code which works fine without transaction
Yet, when I try to use code with transaction
[void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:\MySql.Data.dll")

$ConnectionString = "server=$MySQLServerAddress; port=$MySQLServerPort; database=$MySQLDatabase; uid=$MySQLUsername; pwd=$MySQLPassword;"

$connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($connectionString)

$connection.Open()

$transaction = $connection.BeginTransaction()

try {

    $command1 = $connection.CreateCommand()
    $command1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (value1, value2) VALUES ('1366', 'jsjsjs')"
    $command1.ExecuteNonQuery()

    $transaction.Commit()
}
catch {
    $transaction.Rollback()
    Write-Host "Error during transaction: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
finally {
    $connection.Close()
}

code fail with exception:
Exception calling "BeginTransaction" with "0" argument(s):
"Could not load file or assembly "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" or one of its dependencies. The specified file was not found."
At line:31 char:1

$transaction = $connection.BeginTransaction()
Copy
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException
Unable to call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:52 char:5

Copy
$transaction.Rollback()
Copy
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

There is now way I can obtain this "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Method from MySQL.Data.dll
I just stuck and dunno what to do
